# How to iterate through a SortedList within a class

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, iterable, sortedlist

G'day,

In the simple code example below I am using a simple List to store multiple Employee objects within an Employees object.  I would like to change the List to a SortedList with the Employee.Number used as the TKey, so that the foreach loop will always print the employees in order of ascending Employee.Number and so that the Item method in the Employees class will retrieve an Employee by its Employee.Number rather than by its index position in the List.

I thought this would be trivial, but I don't seem to be able to syntax right to make the SortedList iterable from outside the Employees class...?  So I would very much appreciate it if somebody could modify my example code to show me the way.

Thanking you for your assistance,

Martin.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      clsEmployees Employees = new clsEmployees();

      Employees.Add(new clsEmployee(3, "Fred"));
      Employees.Add(new clsEmployee(5, "Jane"));
      Employees.Add(new clsEmployee(2, "Bob"));
      Employees.Add(new clsEmployee(1, "Sarah"));

      foreach (clsEmployee Employee in Employees)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", Employee.Number, Employee.Name);
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }

public class clsEmployee
{
    public int Number;
    public string Name;

    public clsEmployee(int SetNumber, string SetName)
    {
        Number = SetNumber;
        Name = SetName;
    }
}

public class clsEmployees : IEnumerable<clsEmployee>
{
    private List<clsEmployee> EmployeeList;

    public clsEmployees()                             { EmployeeList = new List<clsEmployee>(); }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()           { return GetEnumerator(); }
    public IEnumerator<clsEmployee> GetEnumerator()   { return EmployeeList.GetEnumerator(); }

    public void Add(clsEmployee NewEmployee)          { EmployeeList.Add(NewEmployee); }

    public clsEmployee Item(int Index)                { return EmployeeList[Index]; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your question what specifically you're having trouble with. You don't show any code that attempts to use `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`, so there's no way to know exactly what you're doing wrong.

Here is how I might approach it:

```
public class clsEmployees : IEnumerable<clsEmployee>
{
    private SortedList<int, clsEmployee> EmployeeList;

    public clsEmployees()
    {
        EmployeeList = new SortedList<int, clsEmployee>();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<clsEmployee> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return EmployeeList.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(clsEmployee NewEmployee)
    {
        EmployeeList.Add(NewEmployee.Number, NewEmployee);
    }

    public clsEmployee Item(int Index)
    {
        return EmployeeList[Index];
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` type requires two type parameters. The first is the key type and the second is the value type. Your key is the `Number` property and so has to be type `int`, while the value is the `clsEmployee` object itself and so has to be that type.
- When enumerating, you just want the values in the collection, not the key/value pairs that would be enumerating using the whole collection. So you should return the `Values` property's `GetEnumerator()` result.
- When adding a new object, you need to specify the key value. Hence, `NewEmployee.Number`
- The `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` type's indexer works just like you want, so no need to change anything there. :)
- I did not change any of your naming. But I do agree that you would benefit from learning and following Microsoft's naming conventions.

This looks a lot like homework. If it's part of an assignment, you should probably still review your uncertainty and difficulty with the teacher, so that they can make sure you've learned the concepts that they want you to learn.

Comment: Thanks very much, your answer hit the spot exactly.  It was your second point I was stuck on - return EmployeeList.VALUES.GetEnumerator(); - I just couldn't see that...  .'s the

Comment: Thanks very much, your answer hit the spot exactly.  It was your second point I was stuck on - return EmployeeList.VALUES.GetEnumerator(); - I just couldn't see that...  As for you questioning if its homework, let me assure you it is not (well, its work-at-home, but not homework the way you mean it)  In fact I am an electronics hardware engineer in my 50's.  I cut my programming teeth on Microsoft Level II Basic nearly a million years ago.  Much later I did a lot of VB 3, 5 and 6.  These days its mostly C and C++ on embedded systems, but occasionally I dabble in a bit of C#...

Comment: So my code example was deliberately a very simplified example, just enough to make it clear what I wanted to do.  I didn't show my non-working simplified example because I was too confused (or too embarrassed) by it.  Anyway, the real class, which is "clsComponentRequestRecord", is about 400 lines and growing.  Yes, my naming conventions hark back to VB - it's hard to teach old dogs new tricks...  Thanks again, Martin.

Comment: Be very, very careful about this answer - specifically, the `Item(int Index)` method.  It returns `EmployeeList[Index]`.  Since you changed `EmployeeList` to a type of `SortedList<int, clsEmployee>`, you will return the item with the matching TKey , **not** the nth item in the list.  For example, based of your example data, `Employees[1]` will return Sarah.  `Employees[0]` will throw an exception.  This might be intended... or you might need to go back and fix a bunch of code.  See my answer below for the other implementation of `Item(int Index)`

Comment: @Yeager: from the original question: _"so that the Item method in the Employees class will retrieve an Employee by its Employee.Number rather than by its index position"_. It is clear that the thing you "warn" about is exactly the thing the OP wants. Your answer, given the question posted above, is simply incorrect.

Comment: @PeterDuniho My bad - you are correct. I have removed my answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to create a new type, what you can do is sort your list using LINQ each time you want to iterate on it

```
  clsEmployees Employees = new clsEmployees();
  Employees.Add(new clsEmployee(3, "Fred"));
  Employees.Add(new clsEmployee(5, "Jane"));
  Employees.Add(new clsEmployee(2, "Bob"));
  Employees.Add(new clsEmployee(1, "Sarah"));

  var sortedList = Employees.OrderBy(t => t.Number);
  foreach (var employee in sortedList)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", Employee.Number, Employee.Name);
  }

  Console.ReadLine();
```

PS : You seem to be a little confused about C#'s syntax conventions. I suggest you take a look at MSDN's Coding Conventions : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx

Comment: @Authur Attout  Thanks for this.  I was kind of aware of something like this possibility, but I want to go with the SortedList  If interested, see also my comments to Peter Duniho's solution.  Thanks again, Martin.